# Failing when trying to append <div>'s with jquery, append not succesful?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to append a div to the end of another div. I am doing this on click of the #driver-button and appending it to the .driver-form.  Right now nothing happens. I have other Jquery working on the page so it is not a loading problem.

Here is my script.  I use preventDefault to prevent the default submit action of the button since it is inside a form.  I also gave the button a type of button in the html.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
       my working js is here.
        var x = 1;
        $('#driver').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            if(x < 6){
                x++;
                $('.driver-form').append('<div class="form-group">
  <label for="inputDriver" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Name</label>
  <div class="col-lg-10">
    <input class="form-control" id="inputDriver" placeholder="" type="text">

  </div>
</div>')
            }



        });







    });







  </script>
```

I am positive I am selecting the proper elements in my script but I can upload the html if you need proof.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using your quotes correctly. Try:

```
$('.driver-form').append('<div class="form-group">' +
  '<label for="inputDriver" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Name</label>' +
  '<div class="col-lg-10">' +
    '<input class="form-control" id="inputDriver" placeholder="" type="text">' +
  '</div>' +
'</div>')
```

Here's a working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/57ea40h6/)

Comment: you either write the html you want to add in a  single row or you must concatenate the string

Comment: I will try that and let you know if it works.  Is there a way to not have to use the + signs? because for simplicity's sake I left out a lot of the html I am trying to append.

Comment: Either add it in a single row, or use the `+` signs, as @Jkike said.
I reccommend using the `+` signs

Comment: I can't get it to work.  I'll checkout the fiddle which I just saw.  Does anyone know if this would be easier with php?

Comment: The fiddle works but will not work in my project still.  Could it have anything to do with the div I am trying to append to?

Comment: You said you were selecting everything correctly.. Maybe you aren't? Post your HTML and the code you really want to implement, and look out for errors in your console.

Comment: I was but then something got changed when I put in your working edit.  Now it is fixed thanks!